# Why does CSS get displayed differently, even for exact same element?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I have 4 panels that are identical. However, on my browser I noticed that the style actually looks different for one element, as I circled with yellow. The red background leaks out. Why could this be?

```
//HTML
<%= 4.times do %>
<div class="col-lg-3">
<div class="profile_card">
  <div class="card_image">
  </div>
  <div class="card_info">
  </div>
  <div class="card_username">
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

and

```
//CSS.SCSS
.profile_card {
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 200px;

  .card_image {
    position: absolute;
    width: 78%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 75%;
    background-color: green;
  }

  .card_info {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 22%;
    margin-left: 78%;
    height: 75%;
    background-color: blue;
  }

  .card_username {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    height:25%;
    background-color: orange;
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks very much like a rounding issue since you are using percentages.

Comment: Ah I see - that could very well be the issue. Btw, on a separate note, if I wanted to add content into .card_username, how would I go about doing that? Currently the bottom red is only showing because it is the remaining bg of the parent .profile_card. Essentially, how do I make it show bg: orange?

Comment: .card_username does not appear to have a width - that might be why it isn't showing (absolutely positioned elements are made as narrow as possible rather than as wide). If you add content it should show up just fine.

Comment: So what would be the best way to retain the width percentage, while getting rid of the ugly gap?

Comment: why dont you just change the profile_card background color to blue? that would get rid of the gap visibility

Comment: On which browser you are observing this?

Answer (score 1):

Give `.card-image, .card-info { float:left; }`

instead of giving left margin to`.card-info`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

```
*{
 -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box
}
```